# How to change HTML value of something using requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-requests, python-requests-html

I want to change the HTML value of a form in a website. Basically just input text into the search algorithm.
Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://website')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="lxml")
findsearch = soup.find(id="search")
```

I want to change the value of suggestion-search, when you print `findsearch` it ends with

```
type="text" value=""/>
```

How do I change the value using requests?

OK, so it seems like you can't use requests to do it. Here's my solution using selenium. You also have to import `webdriver` and `Keys`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://website")
make_search = driver.find_element_by_id("ssearch")
make_search.click()
make_search.send_keys(search_term)
make_search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: You cannot. To simulate behavior that you want you need to use something like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: This approach is indeed used for Selenium. If you want to reproduce this in requests, you'll have to replicate the request(s) the search bar is making. [this might help you](https://kiwidamien.github.io/using-api-calls-via-the-network-panel.html) have an idea how to do this with the help of built in features on modern browsers